# ListView.builder items not getting aligned in center inside a container with scroll direction horizontal

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my Widget:

```
// the category selector widget

class CategorySelector extends StatefulWidget {
  const CategorySelector({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CategorySelectorState createState() => _CategorySelectorState();
}

class _CategorySelectorState extends State<CategorySelector> {
  // categories
  List<String> categories = ['Messages', 'Online', 'Groups', 'Requests'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: 80,
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, // FIXME: doesn't work
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: categories.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text(categories[index]);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Current Output**

[image]

The issue is that ListView.builder items not getting aligned in the center inside a container with scroll direction horizontal. I want to align the ListView items in the center left. May I know how can I do it?

Comment: Try wrapping `Text` with a `Center` widget.

Comment: @esentis Thanks! It worked. May I know the reason that why it happened?

Comment: The starting point of the widgets are top left, that's where `Text` starts in your `ListView`. I always do sanity check of widgets by wrapping the items with `Container` and giving them a distinct color, like red, to see where they are actually aligned. This helps to get a better grasp how widgets are aligned.

Comment: So the ListView took the height of the container and when I was trying to center it, it was already at the center because of that same height, hence I needed to align the content in the center instead?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, ListView always get the full size of her parent height/width depends on scrollDirection. That's we need to define listview height/width. For yours, scrollDirection are horizontal, so the solution is

```
      Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: 80,
        alignment: Alignment.center, // FIXME: does it work for you?
        child: Container(
          height: 14,
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: categories.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text(categories[index], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),);
            },
          ),
        ),
      )
```

[image]